# Rolled my own tooltips, Firefox throwing uncaught exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

It seems I've angered Firefox. Here's a [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTmnU/4/) of what's going on. But, to explain it quickly:

I'm using Mustache.js to render a template. Then, I'm using `.css` to set it to `display : block` and `opacity : 0`. Then, I'm setting the `.offset` and animating to `opacity : 1`.

All works well in Webkit, but not so much in Firefox. I get the following error:

> uncaught exception: [Exception...
>   "Could not convert JavaScript argument
>   arg 0
>   [nsIDOMViewCSS.getComputedStyle]"
>   nsresult: "0x80570009
>   (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)"
>   location: "JS frame ::
>   http://path/to/jquery-1.4.3.js
>   :: anonymous :: line 5223" data: no]

Any ideas where I might be going wrong here?

The error is only thrown when the .offset and .animate calls are in the code. Else, the code runs fine, although of course, the opacity is not animated to 1.

Comment: I'd scaffold the code with a bunch of `try..catch` blocks to narrow down the problem area.

Comment: Hey Ates, thanks for the comment. I clarified at the bottom of my question the exact problem area :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the comments from typeTemplate and appTemplate.

```
typeTemplate : "<div class='tooltip'><a href='#' class='close'>Close</a><p>{{appType}}</p></div>",    

appTemplate : "<div class='tooltip'><a href='#' class='close'>Close</a><p class='title'>{{appName}}</p><p>More information coming soon!</p></div>",
```

I troubleshot it by making a local copy of the site, JSFiddle was bogging down firebug to the point it crashed Firefox. Anyways, I put a debugger on line 5224(where it was dying) of the jQuery source and looked at the last values before it broke.

Here's a screen shot(open it in a new tab) of what I saw in firebug right before the error got thrown. I know it's kinda hard to see but you can read the text in the data value as `" end .tooltip"`. Why it was trying to compute the style of a comment, I don't know :P

[image]

Comment: So r-dub, I was trying to dupe this live to get practice with the debugger, and I can't seem to quite get what you're getting. This is what my window is like: http://d.pr/7ik8 -- thoughts on where I could be going wrong in my debugging?

Comment: You're gtg. Keep hitting the blue play button till the error comes up taking note of the elem value the whole time. When you see the elem show up as a Comment object the next time you hit play you'll see the error show up.

Answer (score 0):

I would add some logging to watch the computed positions/offsets you're setting with CSS. It could be that you're getting a `NaN` or some other awkward value that the browser doesn't like.

Comment: Unfortunately, clickedLeft and clickedTop both evaluate correctly and work if I substitute actual values, so it seems this isn't the issue. Thanks so much, though. Any more ideas are welcomed.